# How to use Esapi 1.4.4 package in web application

Tags: java, esapi, jdk1.4

I am currently working on a project that uses JDK 1.4. So its just turned out to be that we have to use ESAPI 1.4.4 which is the only version compatible with JDK 1.4 . I downloaded it from the following path https://github.com/esapi/esapi-java-legacy but it doesnt seem to be a jar file . I couldnt figure out how to include this in my eclipse project or how to bring it into my classpath. Is it possible to get the JAR ??? Someone please guide me how to use it or any sample project for reference is sufficient .Thanks in advance

Comment: Both of these are a very bad idea.  You’d gain more security by ditching Java 1.4 than by adding ESAPI 1.4 which has its own CVEs and weak crypto.

Comment: @avgvstvs but unfortunately I have no other option . I have to use only this two  please guide m

Comment: I have guided you.

Answer (score 0):

Ditching JDK 1.4 is my top recommendation as well. But if that is not an option for some reason, then I would try pulling down the ESAPI code base from GitHub (https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy), changing the  tag under the maven-compiler-plugin plugin from 1.7 to 1.4 and see if it compiles. Much of it probably will be fine, but you likely will have some huge 3rd party FOSS dependency issues so you will have to adjust those. So, before you go down that route, figure out what exactly it is that you need. If you only need ESAPI's output encoding, use the OWASP Java Encoder Project instead. Various other substitutes are described here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=Should_I_use_ESAPI_3F

Good luck.
-kevin